# How can I convert alphanumeric string into numeric in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have a data frame x, as given below. I want to convert into a data frame y.

```
x <- data.frame(x=c("100A", "200B", "300C"))
y <- data.frame(x=c(100, 200, 300))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match one or more non-numeric characters, replace it with blank `""` and convert to `numeric` (`as.numeric`)

```
y <- transform(x, x=as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", x)))
```

Comment: @SahbanTariq  Here, 'df' is the object name.  In your first example, 'x' is the object name.  So just replace 'x' with 'df' i.e. `dfN <- transform(df, x=as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", x)))`